# DS18B20 temperature sensor not working on Raspberry Pi 3 Model

Tags: temperature

I've connected a temperature sensor (DS18B20) to my Pi and want to read it using 1-wire, but it doesn't work.

I have loaded the w1-gpio and w1-therm modules, added them to /etc/modules and rebooted a bunch of times.

This is the contents of /sys/bus/1w/devices:

ls

w1_bus_master1

i am using LM35 SENSOR

Answer (score 2):

A LM35 sensor is not a DS18B20.

The LM35 signals the temperature by generating an analogue voltage proportional to the temperature which must be read by an external ADC attached to the Pi.

A DS18B20 is a digital sensor which signals the temperature by sending a digital bit pattern down a 1-wire bus (single wire) connected to the Pi.

You need to buy an ADC, e.g. a MCP3008 or similar.